# How to spliit a string from required position in ios

Tags: ios, string

hi I have a number like `94777777777` what I want to do is to remove the 94 and get only 777777777 as a string. How I can do this in ios

Thanks

Comment: Is it only ever going to be 94777777777? What about 95777777777? 94777777776? 94777777777777777? What are your rules and what's the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *output = [yourString substringFromIndex:2];
```